# SimpleDateFormat fails on particular date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

On java 1.8 this code fails

```java
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
dateFormat.parse("03/11/2007 02:05:01");
```

Interesting, that `03:05:01` parses correctly

Comment: How does it fail? Does it produce an error, if so what is that error? My guess is that 03/11/2007 is when DST went into effect, so 02:05 is not a valid time as at 02:00 it jumped to 03:00.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, that's because 2007-03-11T02:05:01 never occurred in the America/New_York time zone.

The spring-forward daylight saving change occurred at 2007-03-11T07:00:00Z, so anyone watching a time-zone-aware clock would have seen:

- 01:59:58
- 01:59:59
- 03:00:00
- 03:00:01

You've told the `SimpleDateFormat` to handle the input strictly, then given it a date/time that didn't exist, so it's reasonable for it to fail.

Importantly, regardless of how you want to handle this, I would *strongly* encourage you to move off the legacy `Date`/`Calendar`/`DateFormat` types, and use `java.time` instead.

Comment: Very good answer Jon. I can add that in effect if you use setLenient(true) both dateFormat.parse("03/11/2007 02:05:01"); and dateFormat.parse("03/11/2007 03:05:01"); are parsed to the same date that is Sun Mar 11 07:05:01 GMT 2007. This answer should be accepted

Comment: is there a way to log such exceptions? Default ParseException is too obscure in such cases. The proper one should be smt like Time doesn't exist

Comment: @IgorWiwi: I don't know of any distinction made by `SimpleDateFormat`. If you move to a better API (java.time) that may well give a more useful error message...